# help with accessing an array/object

Tags: php

i have printed out the contents of an array/object (named 'document') with print_r. it looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 7006276 ) [name] => Arnessysla [type] => region [latitude] => 64.5833 [longitude] => -21.8833 [entities] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) )
```

how do i get the 'entities' contents?

i've tried this: $document[0]->attributes['entities']

but it didnt work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$document[0]->entities
```

`@attributes` is an array, but it ends after the first element because that's where the parens close. `entities` is a separate attribute of the same object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$document[0]->entities
```